My flask cookie does not expire after logout of my website
I have created a website with login and logout function but when i logout the session does not expire because if i save my session cookie before logout and inject it after logout the cookie is still valid but i don't want that for security purpose.
This is what the code look like :
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()
    flash("Déconnecté avec succès !")
    return redirect(url_for("index"))


The convention in Flask is to pop a specific user key from its sessions to invalidate the cookies:
According to the documentation:
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop(KEY, None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

session.clear() is not functioning properly in your example as you must have set up the environment incorrectly, thus the function is doing nothing. But we need more code to pinpoint the precise issue.

You should pop only the related userID or somthing which you have already put in session
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

By poping out relevent key you can validate logout.
For more details check this Flask Documentation
